# Angular material <mat-table>, design is not coming correctly if do the window.print()

Tags: angular

I am using Angular material 6 to display the data into the grid using material  as below. For print option, "printReport()" method is called, where HTML content is taken from the view and call the window.print().

Here, the design is not coming properly in the print page. if we use the table, it comes good. If we use angular material mat-table, the design is not coming correctly.

Any idea to do the print option using ?

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons"
        (click)="printReport('reportMainContent')">local_printshop</i></a>
  </div>
<mat-table>
<ng-container matColumnDef="WorkOrder">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let job" class="fontsize10">{{user.name}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

> .ts file

```
printReport(printSectionId: string) {
    let popupWinindow;
    const innerContents = document.getElementById(printSectionId).innerHTML;
    popupWinindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1900,height=950,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
    popupWinindow.document.open();
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.scss" /></head><body onload="window.print()"><div>' + innerContents + '</div></html>');
    popupWinindow.document.close();
  }
```

Comment: most probably it will just not find the styles needed etc?  how does a screenshot look?  is it not an option to output to pdf or something?

Comment: table wise display is not coming

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: There is no error. But, design is not aligned as per the table since print dom does not understand the <mat-table></mat-table>

Comment: yes, this is what I thought would happen.  I see maybe 2 options you can still try: 
 go the route with a material dialog instead of crafting your own quick fix popup. 
  it will surely understand material markup better.   and the other way i can think of is to convert the inner html to pdf.  but then again does it understand angular material tags

Answer (score 0):

I needed to print a report from the front-end and I built a function that generates the report of the chosen HTML element and its styling, including mat-table. To use it, just add id to the HTML element of the mat-table structure and send it by parameter in the function, which will assemble the PDF and print it complete.

```
<div id='table'> 
  <mat-table></mat-table> 
</div>
```

The ID will be used as a reference to fetch the HTML structure through `document.getElementById(printSectionId)` and add it to the body of the structure to be printed, while `document.querySelectorAll('style')` will fetch all the existing styles of the page.

```
  static print(printSectionId: string): void {
    const styles = this.getElementTag('style');
    const links = this.getElementTag('link');
    const selectionHtml: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(printSectionId);
    const popupWindow = window.open('', 'Extrato', 'top=0,left=0,height=920px,width=1080px');
    popupWindow.document.open();
    popupWindow.document.write(`
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Extrato</title>
        ${styles}
        ${links}
      </head>
      <body>
        ${selectionHtml.innerHTML}
        <script defer>
          function triggerPrint(event) {
            window.removeEventListener('load', triggerPrint, false);
            setTimeout(function() {
              closeWindow(window.print());
            }, 0);
          }
          function closeWindow(){
              window.close();
          }
          window.addEventListener('load', triggerPrint, false);
          window.addEventListener('load', getHeaderFooter, false);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>`);
    popupWindow.document.close();
  }

  static getElementTag(tag: string): any {
    const html = [];
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(tag);
    elements.forEach(element => html.push(element.outerHTML));
    return html.join('\r\n');
  }
```